# Embedded Storage Alternatives for NodeJS

Tags: database, node.js, sqlite, embedded-database

I need to implement a simple key-value storage for a nodejs application, for some environmental restrictions I can only use an embedded storage solution, meaning I can't use engines that work as a separate server/process (E.g. Mongodb, mysql, etc).

For some corporate restrictions I can't use **sqlite**, which was the first option that came to mind.

I investigated the following alternatives to sqlite:

- leveldb (https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/)
- hamsterdb (http://hamsterdb.com/)

I don't have any experience working with these engines, can somebody provide notes or suggentions on these? And of course any other alternative for me to check out is greatly welcomed.

Edit:

With further investigation I found

- NEDB (https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb)
- EJDB (https://github.com/Softmotions/ejdb-node)

Which seem more suitable for Nodejs.

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Thus I flagged this question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the noted databases, the most well supported by Node.js is leveldb, via the [`level`](https://npmjs.org/package/level) module. Just

```
npm install level
```

for everything you need to get started. `level` is a metapackage that bundles [levelUP](https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup) (exposes the leveldb methods) and [`levelDOWN`](https://github.com/rvagg/node-leveldown) (compiles and provides an interface to leveldb). See the `levelUP` documentation for the `exports` provided by `level`.

It's worth noting that this is a suitable solution only if your application will be running on a single machine, since the database is saved to the filesystem. If you scale to multiple servers you'll need to move away from an embedded datastore.

Comment: I like your answer, and leveldb looks awesome, but I think i'm going to go with NEDB, precisely for the scalability factor. NEDB uses a subset of mongodb's query syntax, so if at any point I need to distribute the app on multiple server, I can easily switch to mongo.
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I was asking my self the same question 1 year ago, and I went with EJDB.

I needed a portable local storage for a "local" backend.

I've tried it so far with the following configurations:

- MacOSX + node.js + EJDB
- Windows 7 + node.js + EJDB
- Debian + node.js + EJDB

It worked fine for 10 users. I guess you could have more: i'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

json-lines format - it's json, separated by newlines

https://github.com/AlCalzone/jsonl-db - creates a file where each line is in `{"k": "mykey", "v": anything }`

```
const { JsonlDB } = require('@alcalzone/jsonl-db')

db = new JsonlDB(mydbpath)
await db.open()
db.set(key, value)
await db.close()
```